# ActiveMQQueue cannot be resolved to a type spring-boot-sample

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am new to java.I am working on spring boot samples
[example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples)

I am trying to do spring-boot-sample-activemq. 
My pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<groupId>sample.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-sample-activemq</artifactId>
<!-- <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
<name>Spring Boot ActiveMQ Sample</name>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am getting an error in the  below java class(ActiveMQQueue cannot be resolved to a type)

src/main/java/sample/activemq/SampleActiveMQApplication.java

```
package sample.activemq;

import java.util.Queue;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class SampleActiveMQApplication {

@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue("sample.queue");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SampleActiveMQApplication.class, args);
}

 }
```

Two more classes are there which is exactly same as in [Consumer and Producer classes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-activemq/src/main/java/sample/activemq)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved my issue

Run mvn dependency:purge-local-repository to remove all dependencies and force a re-download.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```